# IntelliJ does not exclude test-classes from Run/Debug configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I recently switched from the *Ultimate Edition* to *IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 (Community Edition)*, and the *Community Edition* behaves awkwardly and **fails to run apps** using Run/Debug configurations.

I have a Spring Boot + Maven project with a single module, which is divided to *main* and *test* and their inner *java* folders are marked respectively as *Sources Root* and *Test Sources Root*.
I defined a Run configuration from the *Application* template for running the project, used the classpath of the module and tried to run it.

Every time it **fails to run**, because *target/test-classes* are included in the combined classpath (which does not make sense); while *JUnit* and *Mockito* are excluded (which makes sense).

I shall appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please file an issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. If it's possible to share the sample project, please attach it to the issue created.